# PHP MyAdmin Inserting data twice

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am adding afew tables to a current database that will drive an online menu.

So far I have created the 'Menu Categories' table. Below is the table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `menu_categories` (
  `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cat_id` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `cat_name` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cat_id` (`cat_id`)
)
```

I have yet to write the PHO scripting but just wanted to insert a few dummy categories for testing, but when I insert a category and then browse the table the data has been entered twice, so i get two of each category.

I have looked around and cannot for the life of me figure out why, is this just PHP MyAdmin?

Below are some print screen of inserting data and the end result:

**Inputting the dummy data**

[image: Inputting the dummy data]

**The sql query for inserting dummy data**

[image: The sql query for inserting dummy data]

**Preview of table with duplicate entries**

[image: Preview of table with duplicate entries]

Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks

*edit: I forgot to add that I tried setting the 'cat_id' to unique. Then when I ran the insert command, I then received an error about inserting duplicate data

Comment: Perhaps you (accidentally) ran the `INSERT` command twice?

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response. Honestly I wish that was the case. I have even deleted the table and created it again.

Comment: But you're using phpMyadmin's data insertion form *and* running your own SQL?  (I'm not very familiar with phpMyadmin, so perhaps that is normal?)

Comment: Now Unless I am being incredibly stupid here. When I use the form and click insert it takes me to the SQL query where i then click 'Go', now I assumed this is just showing  me the query that will be run.

Maybe it is running the insert then just showing me the SQL query, I will check this now.

Comment: Ok So yes I was being incredibly dumb here, it shows the SQL query after it has inserted the data. This seems a bit odd to me.

So yes long story short I was inserting twice :/

Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: I actually looked this up for the same reason... I feel it is a very bad UI design... Why else would you show the SQL statement except to allow the user to verify it's correctness BEFORE it is executed? ... to show the user the statement after execution doesn't make any sense as it is too late!

Comment: @AnthonyGriggs I could agree more, it was quite a frustrating hour or so for me :?

Answer (score 33):

Okay, so I was having the same issue, and I finally realized that I was actually inserting data in the table.

I figured it out like this: when you press insert and you fill out the field and press go, you are going to be taken to another page that has the command line query but notice on the top is showing this message: "One row has been inserted, inserted row id 3" in a light green bar.

The mistake that I was making was: I was clicking the "go" button at the bottom of the query line command, and that was just inserting that query in the table again. so, instead of clicking "go" just click the "Browse" button that is on the top navigation bar that's next to the "structure" button.

Comment: Stellar observation. I was having the same issue and I didn't notice that. Yesterday I didn't notice I inserted something twice and it caused hours of debugging because my entire site started to function improperly!

Comment: Wow, great perception! Saved me from putting my fist through my monitor in frustration!

Answer (score 0):

You can work around this if you are adding rows, and then going to add more rows.

Click the drop down on the bottom left where it says "Insert New Row" and then make sure "Insert another new row" is selected in the drop down.

I agree with the above poster as the form behavior does insert it, but then doesn't go back to the page it goes to the SQL screen so strange.  Im posting this here and all this time it still has this behavior when inserting rows.  phpMyAdmin has got to know about this by now no?